# R code in LaTeX in YAML before_body include

Tags: r, latex, yaml, knitr

I have a LaTeX section that I put at the top of my knitr generated PDF document. I achieved this by using the YAML options

```
output:
    pdf_document: 
        includes: 
            before_body: file.tex
```

file.tex contains code like this

```
\textsf{Reporting: `r 2+2`}
```

but this doesn't work. Is there another way that I can get this value? Passing in a parameter is fine if that's possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to knit `file.tex`. I suggest you rename `file.tex`, e.g., to `file.Rnw`, and in your main R Markdown document:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
writeLines(knitr::knit_child('file.Rnw'), 'file.tex')
```
````

Comment: This is really great. I was thinking that the input would have to be there before compile. Now it is obvious that the document is compiled after all of the code has executed. Thanks!