# Apply knitr option function in "before_body" when using Rmarkdown to compile PDF

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

As question, I am using knitr option (i.e. `include=temp.switch`) to compile multiple reports based on the value given to a "switch" (i.e. `temp.switch`), this are working well for the content, but I would like to use similar function to modify the cover page of the report, which is stored in the `tex` file read in yaml, like the one below:

```
---
output: 
    pdf_document:
      # template: template.tex
      number_sections: true
      keep_tex: true
      includes:
        in_header: preamble.tex
        before_body: doc-prefix.tex
papersize: a4
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

Can anyone tell me how to make the `doc-prefix.tex` "conditional" based on the value of the "switch"? Thanks!

Comment: How do you compile your document?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I use the knit function inside R-studio, which I pressed `ctrl-shift-k` to create a tex file, then Miktex is called to compile a PDF file from it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881851/r-code-in-latex-in-yaml-before-body-include should have the solution I need